# Can't load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains in Facebook Login in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, facebook

After Registering my application with Facebook for using Facebook OAuth Login with ASP.NET application i got error. when i am click on Facebook button in Development Environment.

> Can't load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. 
>   To be able to load this URL, add all domains and sub-domains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

**Login Screen**

[image: Login Screen]

**Error Displayed**

[image: Error Displayed]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are getting same Error means you have Enter Wrong URIs in "**Valid OAuth redirect URIs**" while Registering my application with Facebook.

1. Choose App where you are getting error while Registering
2. After Choose App go to "**PRODUCTS**" section in that section choose **Facebook Login** , inside that section choose "**Setting**", after choosing "**Client OAuth Settings**" panel will appear in that there is "**Valid OAuth redirect URIs**" textbox in that just enter your localhost 
   URL [http://localhost: Port Number/signin-facebook].

e.g if you localhost URL is "http://localhost:8000/Account/Login"
then  while entering in "**Valid OAuth redirect URIs**" textbox enter "http://localhost:8000/signin-facebook" and click on Save Changes

**Registering Facebook Application**

[image: Registering Facebook Oauth]

Comment: where is 'signin-facebook' coming from?

Comment: @Scott They put it that way in the microsoft docs tutorial. Here is the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-pt/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/facebook-logins?tabs=aspnetcore1x

Comment: hello valid Oauth redirect URis still same error plz solution

Comment: in my case when i live my app always comming this error not working even on local host when in development local work not with domain url

Answer (score 1):

Just write carefully in your OAuth Redirect URI: `http://{ your host }:{ port number }` (e.g. `http://example.com:8000`).

Comment: Hi Rash, please be careful when posting links similar to your username; they can be picked up as spam if you are not careful. I have edited your example link to fix this issue but it looks like some folks have already downvoted you because of it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts you need fill in.
Both on the right side of your app setting panel.

1. Settings -> Advanced -> Domain Manager( Add Your URL)
2. PRODUCTS ->  Facebook Logion -> Settings -> Valid OAuth redirect URIs
   Here to add your URL.